# TYPO3 6.2 functional testing error

Tags: typo3-6.2.x

I want to run typo3 functional tests for my extension, but I get the following error:

```
Call to a member function admin_query() on a non-object in /x/y/z/TYPO3.DIR/typo3/sysext/core/Tests/FunctionalTestCaseBootstrapUtility.php on line 493
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command to run functional tests of your extension:

```
typo3conf/ext/phpunit/Composer/vendor/bin/phpunit -c typo3/sysext/core/Build/FunctionalTests.xml typo3conf/ext/<YOU_EXT_DIR>/Tests/Functional/
```